# Mailchimp v3 - Retrieve only members names and email from an specific list

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I want to retrieve an array of members from an specific list. But instead of a big response, i'm interested only in their names, emails and, maybe, their id.

I got this code that works fine to retrieve every detail of a member in a list

```
$ch = curl_init(REQUEST_URL.$list.'/members/');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . API_KEY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  $error = curl_error ( $ch );
  curl_close($ch);
```

But if I try to add the fields I want in the request URL, i get a 422 error:

> "Requested Fields Invalid" "Some of the fields requested were invalid:
>   member.first_name"

What is the correct way to make this request? Only some fields from all the members in a specific list?

thank you guys!

Comment: how do you add the fields? REQUEST_URL.$list.'/members/?fields=first_name,email'  like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you can pass required fields

```
$ch = curl_init(REQUEST_URL.$list.'/members/?fields=members.id,members.email_address');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . API_KEY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  $error = curl_error ( $ch );
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for the answer to this for a good few hours. It was the members.id (with the dot) that got me. The MailChimp documentation is pretty woeful.